# How to match the following regex expression

Tags: php, regex, tags

I am really new to Regex and still, I am trying to understand the way it works. I am trying to develop a regex to capture name and value from input tag in HTML.

`<input type='hidden' name='student' value='9208'>`

My idea is to extract the value related to name(student) and the value(9208).
I have developed the following regex based on an earlier answer in the stakcoverflow for a previous question.

`/<(input)(?:\s+type=([\'"]?)(?<type>[^\'"]*?)\2\s*)?(?:\s+name=([\'"]?)(?<name>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)?(?:\s+value=([\'"]?)(?<value>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)?>/m`

Above regex is working properly with input like

`<input type='hidden' name='student' value='9208'>`

But, it is not capturing string if there is no single quotation marks or double quotation marks around the value corresponding with the value attribute (**value='9208'**)
eg-

`<input type='hidden' name='student' value=9208>`

In the above case, it didn't give any matches. Can someone help me to fix the above regex?
Thank you

Comment: You don't generally want to use regex to parse HTML. Instead use an XML parser like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: I will give it a try.Is there any particular reason for not using regex to parse HTML? It seems that it is possible.I  am really new to this.

Comment: @Shota yes... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags **TL;DR** *Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp.*

Comment: @Andreas Thanks,I got the idea

Comment: If the use case is very simple, you can sometimes get by with regex and you'll be fine. However, HTML as a whole can not be handled by regex alone, and once you get past very simple patterns, it's just simpler and safer to use an XML parser.

Comment: @Alex Howansky I will give it a try. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small problem in your regex.

```
<(input)(?:\s+type=([\'"]?)(?<type>[^\'"]*?)\2\s*)?(?:\s+name=([\'"]?)(?<name>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)?(?:\s+value=([\'"]?)(?<value>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)?>
```

Here if you notice, in your this regex part `(?<value>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)` you are using `\4` as closing quote or double quote, but `\4` is the capture group in name regex part `(?<name>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)`, hence if value attribute is also enclosed by the same character, doublequote or single quote, then your regex will match fine but if name attribute's value is enclosed by something different than value attribute part, then your regex will simply not match.

So you just need a little correction and make it `\6` in `(?<value>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)` part and your regex will start matching like you expected.

Here is the correct regex you should use,

```
<(input)(?:\s+type=([\'"]?)(?<type>[^\'"]*?)\2\s*)?(?:\s+name=([\'"]?)(?<name>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)?(?:\s+value=([\'"]?)(?<value>[^\'"]*?)\6\s*)?>
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ot1Z14/1)**

Comment: thank you very much for the support and it means a lot to me

Comment: Pleased to help brother :)

Comment: I ran into a small problem while using the above regex. When I run the following code on my local server,  it is not working as expected.But,it is working properly when I check it on regular expressions 101.

Comment: `$html_1 ="<td valign='middle'><input type='submit' value='Personal Information'><input type='hidden' name='student' value=9208><input type='hidden' name='task' value='fill'>";
$re_1 = '<(input)(?:\s+type=([\'"]?)(?<type>[^\'"]*?)\2\s*)?(?:\s+name=([\'"]?)(?<name>[^\'"]*?)\4\s*)?(?:\s+value=([\'"]?)(?<value>[^\'"]*?)\6\s*)?>';
preg_match_all($re_1, $html_1, $matches_1);
$var_1=sizeof($matches_1);
$count_1 = count($matches_1[0]);` 
 When I print the contetnt of the $matches_1 array,values filelds are not included.But,in regex 101 site,it shows that the variables are included

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comments to your post that using regex to parse HTML in not a good idea.
But it is still possible, although it requires you to be very accurate and observant.

In your case the regex can be as follows (for readability I divided it into chunks):

- `<(input)` - `<` and the first capturing group, matching the tag name.
- `(?:\s+type=([\'"]?)(?<type>[^\'"]+)\2)?` - The part for `type` attribute.
- `(?:\s+name=([\'"]?)(?<name>[^\'"]+)\4)?` - The part for `name` attribute.
- `(?:\s+value=([\'"]?)(?<value>[^\'"]+)\6)?` - The part for `value` attribute.
- `\s*>` - A sequence of spaces and `>` terminating the tag.

Your failure is that in the part concerning `value` you called group No 4,
but you should have called group No 6.

Another correction is that if the next group starts with `\s+` then the current
group dous not need to end with `\s*` (as you did).

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/IOLKTV/1